# tortoiseSVN commit fails - not allowed to commit changes, but same user can commit from ubuntu cli command

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to commit through tortoiseSVN, Windows7, but get the following error:
[image]

I've been able to commit these files through ubuntu cli commands.

marked in yellow is the SVN folder i checkedout, and trying to add a couple of directories with a couple of files each
I've already read in stackoverflow and did the following:

1. [solution number 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540827/fixing-the-subversion-user-does-not-own-lock-on-path-error), which didn't help, in my check for modification there's no locks, but there's question marks in the remote text:
   [image]
2. i've tried killing the SVN process and restarting the computer.
3. i've tried doing a new checkout and adding to that then commiting, same error
4. i've check with my sys admin, and he double checked my permissions.

I'm really at a loss why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact you server admin again because it's clear that the pre-commit hook script that's configured on the repository does not allow you to commit these changes. You can't solve the problem yourself, it's the task of your admin.

It seems that the pre-commit hook script rejects your commits because it's configured to do so or it's broken.