# git grep and xargs in Windows Batch file?

Tags: windows, git, bash, batch-file, xargs

I am trying to create a Windows friendly `.bat` implementation of the following `.sh` script. The top few lines are all fine, just add `SET` and cd is fine. git grep is fine, however, `xargs` isn't... What would the `git grep | xargs` logic look like in `.bat` ?

```
INFINITY=10000

TOPDIR=$(pwd)
METEOR_DIR="./code"
cd "$METEOR_DIR"

# Call git grep to find all js files with the appropriate comment tags,
# and only then pass it to JSDoc which will parse the JS files.
# This is a whole lot faster than calling JSDoc recursively.
git grep -al "@summary" | xargs -L ${INFINITY} -t \
    "$TOPDIR/node_modules/.bin/jsdoc" \
    -t "$TOPDIR/jsdoc/docdata-jsdoc-template" \
    -c "$TOPDIR/jsdoc/jsdoc-conf.json" \
    2>&1 | grep -v 'WARNING: JSDoc does not currently handle'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any recent [Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) has more than 200 Linux commands packaged in it.

Add to your PATH `<path\to\Git\usr\bin` and you will have `xargs`.

```
vonc@VONCM D:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.9.2-64-bit\usr\bin
> dir xargs.exe

 Directory of D:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.9.2-64-bit\usr\bin

20/01/2016  10:17            64 058 xargs.exe
```

Comment: Mented xargs port depend on some external libraries, try to use native xargs port http://www.pirosa.co.uk/demo/wxargs/wxargs.html instead

Comment: @user2956477 why? All external libraries are packages with Git for Windows.

Comment: Its always better to have single native binary without dependency, it minimize possible troubles

Comment: @user2956477 OK, makes sense. But in reality, I don't bother, because there are 200 Linux commands already working.